# Taking Data from worksheets to single workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I received excel data that has a separate worksheet with data for each day.  I would like to take one cell (ie: cell B5) of from each worksheet and compile that data into a single worksheet.  What is my most efficient course of action.

Comment: Please select an answer to help users with the same issue find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your *"most efficient"* way about doing this is going to be:

```
=Sheet1!B5
=Sheet2!B5
=Sheet3!B5
 etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in C2:C5 of a blank worksheet.

```
 =ADDRESS(5,2,1,1,INDEX({"Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3","Sheet4"},ROW()-1))
```

You will get this result.

```
Sheet1!$B$5
Sheet2!$B$5
Sheet3!$B$5
Sheet4!$B$5
```

You could write the sheet names in a range, like A1:A4 and replace the direct range in the formula `{"Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3","Sheet4"}` to make the formula look like this.

```
=ADDRESS(5,2,1,1,INDEX($A$1:$A$4,ROW()-1))
```

Observe that ROW()-1 is a counter that returns 1 in row 2, 2 in row 3 etc. If you don't start in row 2 you need to adjust the *-1*.

Now, for your solution, you simply embed the formula just created in an INDIRECT() function, thus.

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(5,2,1,1,INDEX($A$1:$A$4,ROW()-1)))
```

Write the formula in one cell and copy down for as long as your list of worksheets might be.